# OIDC SSO Authorization Server with external login app

Tags: authentication, authorization, singleton, openid-connect

I am programming my own authorization server in nodejs/typescript with nestJS and TypeORM and would like to have my login app separated as angular app. How does the open id connect workflow handle this type of redirect?

Does the /authorize endpoint redirect to the login app and the login app redirects back after successfull login? And how does the date be transfared in a secure manner?

I searched in the official openid connect docs and specifications but cannot find any information about the usage of external login apps / identity providers.